# Computer comparison

Tags: performance, compilation, benchmarking

I have access to many different computers, and I want to compare their performance.

So I ran a benchmark program, and wanted to see on which computer it runs faster.

Is it important where I compile the program? Are there compilation flags that make it matter (like `-xhost` or `-march=native`)?

Comment: Yes `-O3 -march=native`  ISA extensions and tuning make a difference (or `-march=znver2` or whatever), but what to choose depends what you want to know: how fast the computer is running this specific program tuned for itself, or running a generic binary, or whatever.

Comment: I want to run a specific program on different computers and compare run times. I wanted to know whether it is important or not to compile on the same computer I run on. I understand from your answer that it is important only when I use flags like `-O3 -march=native`